# JavaScript code not working with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML file, the JS doesn't seem to work and does not append new rows to the file! Please tell me where am I going wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Title </title>
<link href = "">
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "container col-sm-6">
    <table class = "table table-bordered">
    <tr class = "col-sm-offset-2">
        <th>User_Name</th>
        <th>score</th>
        <th>team</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var json = [{"User_Name":"John Doe","score":"10","team":"1"},{"User_Name":"Jane Smith","score":"15","team":"2"},{"User_Name":"Chuck Berry","score":"12","team":"2"}];
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].User_Name + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].score + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].team + "</td>");
            $('table').append(tr);
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't included `jquery.js` in the page. Also note that your variable named `json` is not JSON, but an array of objects.

Comment: Yeah I know that. Included jquery.min.js and it worked just fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add jquery it's working

**[Download jquery](https://jquery.com/download/)** plugin and add

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var json = [{"User_Name":"John Doe","score":"10","team":"1"},{"User_Name":"Jane Smith","score":"15","team":"2"},{"User_Name":"Chuck Berry","score":"12","team":"2"}];
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].User_Name + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].score + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].team + "</td>");
            $('table').append(tr);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class = "container col-sm-6">
    <table class = "table table-bordered">
    <tr class = "col-sm-offset-2">
        <th>User_Name</th>
        <th>score</th>
        <th>team</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
```